# MySQL query takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working on an IOT based application for which I'm storing time series data in MySQL. I have two tables in different databases as follows:

```
describe fo_data.device_data;
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field     | Type                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id        | int                                 | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| device    | varchar(255)                        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| data      | varchar(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| data_type | enum('int','string','bool','float') | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| comment   | varchar(255)                        | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| added_on  | timestamp                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+


describe fo.device_mapping;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id         | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| device     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| company_id | int          | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| added_on   | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| alias      | varchar(140) | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Currently, `device_data` has 75,499,824 rows whereas `device_mapping` has 0

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT distinct(device_data.device) as device, 
       device_mapping.alias 
FROM `fo`.`device_mapping` 
right join fo_data.device_data on device_mapping.device = device_data.device 
where device_data.device like '%all/006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608%';
```

and it's taking around 3 minutes to execute, just to return 9 rows (that match this query)

I used `Explain` to see what is happening but didn't understand what's wrong and how to optimise.

```
explain SELECT distinct(device_data.device) as device, 
               device_mapping.alias 
FROM `fo`.`device_mapping` 
right join fo_data.device_data on device_mapping.device = device_data.device 
where device_data.device like '%all/006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608%';
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                    | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | device_data    | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_device_data_device | 767     | NULL | 75117603 |    11.11 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | device_mapping | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL |        1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong and guide me to how I can make my queries run faster?

**EDIT #1**

```
SELECT distinct(device_data.device) as device, device_mapping.alias 
FROM `fo`.`device_mapping` 
right join fo_data2.device_data on device_mapping.device = device_data.device 
WHERE MATCH(device_data.device) AGAINST('+006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608' IN BOOLEAN MODE);


<after 40 minutes I get this...>

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server

mysql>
```

**EDIT #2**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM device_data WHERE device_data.device like '%all/006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608%';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 20669568 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 43.62 sec)


mysql> show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What value do you get from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devide_data WHERE device_data.device like '%all/006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608%';` ?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames I've edited my question with the results of these commands

Comment: Fix the buffer_pool setting; see the update to my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames I increased the `buffer_pool` to `1.5GB` but still the `select count(*)` query is taking `2 min 9.73 sec` to execute :/

Answer (score 0):

- The leading wildcard (`%`) prevents any index from speeding up this query.  Without the that, I would recommend

  ```
    device_data:  INDEX(device)
    device_mapping:  INDEX(device,  alias)
  ```
- `DISTINCT` is not a function.
- Can there be multiple `aliases` for each `device`.  If not, you should not need the `DISTINCT`.
- If `006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608` is a "word", you can use a `FULLTEXT` index to make it much faster via

  ```
    WHERE MATCH(device) AGAINST('+006b41468b3cb64506fd65e4e4172608'
                                IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ```
- It might make more sense to toss `id` in device mapping and replace the PK with `PRIMARY KEY(device, alias)` (at which point, my suggestion for this table is not needed.)
- If `device` names are unique, shouldn't that be the PK instead of an otherwise useless `id`?

**Important**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM.  (128M is an old, too-small, default.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :) Now that you've mentioned, I realized I can use `device` as a PK in the table `device_mapping`. I'' try to duplicate the database and try out `FULLTEXT` index that you mentioned. [point #3] A single device can have just one alias, however multiple devices can have the same alias. I had used `DISTINCT` as there can me multiple entries with the same device in `device_data`, but just one entry against that device in `device_mapping` and I wanted to extract all the available devices in `device_data` matching a search criteria, and the corresponding aliases set if any.

Comment: I tried creating a `FULLTEXT` index on `device` column of `device_data` table. It took 2 hours to add the index to the table. But even after that when  I ran the query, it just gave me a `Lost connection` error after 45 mins. I've updated the question with the query I used and the response I got

Comment: Was the `SELECT` running for 40 minutes?  Or was the connection sitting idle?

Comment: I think the `select` took that much time, not sure though. Like i typed the query and pressed enter, it was taking time, so after every few minutes i pressed an enter to see if it's working or it throws an error but got no response. Then after this much time it just threw this error message